# Byron's transition from Manfred to Don Juan

Tags: character-analysis, lord-byron, manfred

Manfred is more serious compared to Don Juan's light heartedness. While Manfred lives within the realm of seriousness and continuous self-pity, Don Juan lives in the realm of cynicism as it brings blatantly "inappropriate humor" to rather serious topics that Byron wants to address (mainly the attack on England's hypocrisy).

So, why did Byron's writing become more satirical and ironic?

Comment: I suggest adding a "homework" tag. I know that the site is officially source-agnostic, but I'm sure there are some users to whom a question's provenance might make a difference...

Comment: Just saw [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) on the main meta-SE. In any case, I think this isn't a well-formed question.

Comment: This isn't for "homework"... I was just genuinely curious because I have to read both books and I found it interesting that the Byronic hero changed. (I'm also not an English major and I've barely read throughout my life, so I do enjoy discussions that guide me towards some direction for research) How should I reformat this question? Or is there another forum I can post this in?

Comment: I'm quite new to this corner of the SE world, so I don't want to mislead you. But in general a question should be looking for _one specific, correct answer_, not a discussion.

Comment: @Josh Please see [this site's policy](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/561/17) on homework questions. Also, "correctness" can often be very hard to define when it comes to literary analysis; a well-reasoned, well-supported answer is frequently the best we can hope for here.

Comment: Alright, I tried to reword it... hopefully it's more fitting.